# Cannot get the available resolutions of a USB WebCam

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, .net-6.0, accord.net

I am trying to recode my CineFilmToVideo cine frame capture program using MS Visual Studio 2022 and .NET 6.0 (or newer) C# for target operating system Windows 10.0.22000.0 or later (Win11).

But I get a problem, that I cannot solve.
Whenever I try to get the video capabilities (via **Accord.net** - especially the supported resolutions of the camera ) I get a message, that the dll for **CoreCompat.System.Drawing** is not found and I find no NuGet Package, that provides this dll.

See message:

> "Could not load file or assembly 'CoreCompat.System.Drawing,
> Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Das System
> kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden."

Has anybody an idea where to get the required dll.

Many thanks in advance

Wolfgang

Comment: That package has been superseded by at least two others. You might be able to track it down and find it in some archive. The accord.net package on nuget seems to not be updated since 2017. Doesn't look good for your .NET 6 migration. Things have changed in the last 5 years.

Comment: Look here : https://www.nuget.org/stats/packages/CoreCompat.System.Drawing.v2?groupby=Version&force_isolation=true

Comment: I found out, that AForge can do the trick.

Comment: AForge only work with .NET =< 4.8. No support for .NET 6.0/7.0